# How can use SED to replace a space with a comma

Tags: bash, shell

I've been trying to get this to work with no luck.. I have two values in my script. Right now it has a space, I want to place a comma in-between them.

```
sed -e 's/.*-Xmx16000m //g'
```

Please let me know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but I'm guessing you might want something like

```
sed -e 's/\(-Xmx16000m\) /\1,/g'
```

This will look for the string `-Xmx1600m` followed by a space, and will replace the following space with a comma.  There doesn't need to be anything in particular after it.  Alterantely, you might want

```
sed -e 's/\(pattern1\) \(pattern2\)/\1,\2/g'
```

which will seach for pattern1 and pattern2 separated by a space (these patterns might be any regexp, not just fixed strings), and replace the space between them with a comma.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried `sed -e 's/\(-Xmx16000m\) /\1,/g'`, it takes the space out, but it does not insert the comma..

Comment: Here is example using `sed -e 's/.*-Xmx16000m //g'` `10.0.1.1,1503577131 71511` I want to but a comma in between `1503577131 71511` The sed command does not include the IP address

Comment: what's the idea behind `-Xmx16000m`? also, try this: `echo "10.0.1.1,1503577131 71511" | tr ' ' ','`

Comment: I still get a space, man... I cant seem to figure this out.. grrr ... this is for java `-Xmx16000m` Thx for the help everyone...